# Subversion: good practices to administrate users and groups with the repositories

Tags: svn, http, apache2, system-administration

How should I administrate users and groups with the repositories?

Until now users can access the server repositories through http. The tag configuration it inside /etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf

```
<Location /srv/svn/>
DAV svn
SVNPath /srv/svn/projecX
#SVNParentPath /srv/svn #if I have more the one repository inside the folder
AuthType Basic
AuthName ”ProjectX”
AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

My doubts:

1. For each repository should I have a passwd file containing all users and pass?
2. When is more appropriated to use SVNPath or SVNParentPath ?
3. How do I manage groups? Until know I know how to work with individuals but not with groups in a more optimized way.
4. (EDIT) Users and Group repositories control should be always made through apache2 ?

I'm using Ubuntu server edition for the server repositories.
Thanks for the attention3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage groups and group access to paths in the repository in the `auth` file. You can share the `passwd` file between repositories by creating a symlink. Usually in an entreprise context an ActiveDirectory or alike would be better but rather tedious to bind into svn. We do the authentication at Apache level (mod_ldap/mod_svn_ldap) and the rights checks in svn with a global `auth` file (to ease group definition and reuse). Setting up LDAP is not much of fun thought...

Comment: Using a DBMS would be better?

Comment: the local authentication with passwd file is easy but if your staff is not stable, then you'll have to update this often, what is rather dull work...

Answer (score 0):

*authz_svn* allows directory level user & group authentication. Integrates well with [websvn](http://websvn.tigris.org/). Here is one of the many [tutorials](http://davidwinter.me.uk/articles/2006/03/03/access-control-for-subversion-with-apache2-and-authz/) on the web about how to setup authz_svn.

Comment: Thanks, I'm taking a look at it. What about using a DBMS?

Comment: LDAP, single sign on might be interesting.